# API test using RestSharp keeps returning 'Unauthorized Access, invalid API key'

Tags: api, restsharp

I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of days now and that includes looking at similar posted questions but I can't seem to get it to work.

I am trying to post a request to retrieve a Token which I can then use for further API GET requests.

The request I am posting is the below:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetToken()
    {
        var client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddParameter("Authorization", bearer, ParameterType.HttpHeader);
        request.AddParameter("username", username);
        request.AddParameter("password", password);
        request.AddParameter("api_key", apiKey);
        IRestResponse restResponse = client.Execute(request);

        Console.WriteLine("Status code: " + (int)restResponse.StatusCode);
        Console.WriteLine("Status message " + restResponse.Content);
    }
```

When I run the request, I get the following:
Status code: 200
Status message {"content":null,"error":"Unauthorized Access, invalid API key","success":false}

I cannot figure out why I keep getting the invalid API Key value. In terms of all the variables I use, when I post the request in Postman, it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I had a look at the code with a developer and turned out I needed to be passing in my apikey as part of the AddParameter value. 
So my final code looked like:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetToken()
    {

        var client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddParameter("Authorization", "Bearer " + apiKey, ParameterType.HttpHeader);
        request.AddParameter("username", username);
        request.AddParameter("password", password);
        IRestResponse restResponse = client.Execute(request);

        Console.WriteLine("Status code: " + (int)restResponse.StatusCode);
        Console.WriteLine("Status message: " + restResponse.Content);
    }
```